# Mock svelte component with vitest

Tags: svelte, vite, svelte-component, vitest

I'm trying to mock a Svelte component with Vitest using the `vite-require` plugin.

```
import Select from './__mocks__/select.svelte';

vi.mock('./select.svelte', () => {
  const c = require('./__mocks__/select.svelte').default;

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: vi.fn((args) => {
      return new c(args);
    }),
  };
});

beforeEach(() => {
  vi.restoreAllMocks();
});

describe('test', () => {
  test('test', () => {

    const { container } = render(ParentComponent, { });

    console.log(screen.debug(container));
    console.log(Select as any);
  });
});
```

The `ParentComponent` has the `Select` component on it as a child, and when the test renders the console outputs it correctly. The `Select` has been replaced with the mocked `Select` from the `__mocks__` folder, so the svelte file get compiled correctly.

But when I try to log the mocked `Select` it is of type `[class Proxy<Select> extends ProxyComponent]`, it is not an instance, so I cannot interact with it. I can't access any of the mock objects from vite on it because it is not instantiated.

I have copied this from some existing libraries using jest: https://github.com/IgnusG/svelte-jester-mock

How can I make this work in vitest?